# How to open one tab at a time inside a foreach

Tags: javascript, php, magento2, alpine.js

It's a simple task yet so tricky. I'm trying to open one single tab at time.

I'm using Magento2, dealing with both PHP and AlpineJS.

This is the interested portion of code:

```
<div class="grid lg:grid-cols-2">
    <?php
    foreach ($block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', '') as $key => $sectionName) {
        $sectionBlock  = $block->getLayout()->getBlock($sectionName);
        $sectionHtml   = (string) $sectionBlock->toHtml();
        $titleTemplate = $sectionBlock->getData('title_template') ?? $defaultTitleTemplate;

        if (empty(trim($sectionHtml))) {
            continue;
        }
        ?>


        <section x-data="{ activeTab : '<?= $block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', '')[0] ?>' }" id="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($sectionBlock->getNameInLayout()) ?>">
            <div x-on:click.prevent="activeTab = '<?= $block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', '')[$key] ?>'" class="flex font-light items-center justify-between cursor-pointer" :class="{ 'font-bold' : open }">
                <?=
                $titleRenderer->setTemplate($titleTemplate)
                    ->assign('sectionBlock', $sectionBlock)
                    ->toHtml()
                ?>
            </div>

            <div class="my-6 w-full" x-show="'<?= $block->getGroupSortedChildNames('detailed_info', '')[$key] ?>' === activeTab">
                <?= /** @noEscape  */ $sectionHtml ?>
            </div>
        </section>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I need the first tab to be open by default, then if I click on the next one I can close the other and viceversa.

I don't understand why this is not working, or at least it's working a little bit, but not completely.

I think this is the right way but something is missing.

Can you guys help me please?

Comment: _"or at least it's working a little bit, but not completely"_ - and we are supposed to be able to guess what that is actually supposed to mean now?

Comment: it means that if I open one tab I cannot close it then. So in the end all the tabs are opened.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to make a section element outside the loop.

And for the tab, you can use the x-show attribute to hide/show the tabs in the grid.

Please check the documentation:

```
<div x-data="{ tab: 'foo' }">
    <button :class="{ 'active': tab === 'foo' }" @click="tab = 'foo'">Foo</button>
    <button :class="{ 'active': tab === 'bar' }" @click="tab = 'bar'">Bar</button>
    <div x-show="tab === 'foo'">Tab Foo</div>
    <div x-show="tab === 'bar'">Tab Bar</div>
</div>
```

https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/tree/v2.8.2#readme
https://dev.to/mtownsend5512/creating-powerful-tabs-with-alpine-js-in-less-than-5-minutes-367d

Check the sample working of tabs:
https://codebase-frontend-library.github.io/codebase-4/docs/8-alpinejs-components/alpinejs-tabs/